# Laravel 5 non persistent session

Tags: session, laravel, session-cookies, laravel-5

I'm just installed a fresh L5 app. I'm attempting to use database driven sessions however a new session appears to be created on each page load.

Has anyone come across this issue and managed to resolve?

"_token" value is new on each refresh.

I'm happy that the cookies have been configured correctly.

Not sure where to look next.

Any suggestions would be a huge help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Laravel 5.2.10 Sessions wont persist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958607/my-laravel-5-2-10-sessions-wont-persist)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured your session domain is set correctly? Your session domain should be the domain alone, for example `domain.com`, no URIs or protocols (http://), etc.

You may also want to check that `SESSION_HTTPS` is set to false, unless you're accessing your site over https.

If either are not set correctly sessions will not be correctly stored by the browser, so each request results in a new session.

The `_token` key will always be a new value for each request, this is part of the CSRF security feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. https is set to false and session domain is correct. A new $sessionId is generation on each page load. Cannot work out why :-(