# My Laravel 5.2.10 Sessions wont persist

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, session-cookies

I have a brand new installation of Laravel 5, in fact I have tried this on multiple versions and keep hitting the same issue.

I have not changed anything from the default except setting the session driver to redis.  (File based also has the same issue).

I have two routes set as follows

```
Route::get('/set/{value}', function($value) {
    var_dump(Session::getId());
    Session::set('test', $value);
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/get', function() {
    return 'Get ' . Session::get('test');
});
```

If I visit the url /set/abc I see the session appear in REDIS (I also see the file created when using file based).  The session looks fine in REDIS as shown below

```
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
 1) "laravel:1a3ae6caff6346e4a173fdc1ab4c6eb0f138806b"
 2) "laravel:fed1af2fb44c6e625953237c3fa6fcbb05366a5c"
 3) "laravel:cb37286ccfe3e7caa20557aca840f50cb5a5f20d"
```

Every time I visit the page though, it recreates a new session.

The key parts of session.php file is as follows:

```
'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

I have also checked in REDIS the TTL of the session variables and they do get initialised at 120 minutes (equivalent in seconds).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

It might be worth noting I am using a homestead vm (completely stock) to test this.  I have also tried using multiple browsers.  No cookies are ever sent to the browser, I presume a session id should be sent to the browser as part of the initial get request?

Comment: that's really strange... I'm trying to replicate the behavior locally. I wonder if the `getId` method does something nasty

Comment: @FBidu I have tried with and without the getId function, it doesn't seem to affect it in any way, I get the same odd behavior.

Comment: @FBidu Actually [`getId`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php#L162-L165) does what it implies it does and nothing more :).

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue here!

Comment: @FBidu is this a problem with laravel v5.2.10 ?

Comment: @JonTaylor it seems to be! I'm not being able to fix in any way...

Comment: Thanks guys, I was starting to go crazy, glad it isn't just me :).  I've raised the issue for reference https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12003

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Laravel's middleware class `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession` is responsible for starting your session. Before L5.2, this ran on every request because it was part of the global middleware stack. Now, it's optional because L5.2 wants to allow for both a web UI and an API within the same application.

If you open up `app/Http/Kernel.php`, you'll see that the `StartSession` middleware is part of a middleware group called `web`. You need to put all your routes inside there for your example to work.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/set/{value}', function($value) {
        var_dump(Session::getId());
        Session::set('test', $value);
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/get', function() {
        return 'Get ' . Session::get('test');
    });
});
```

You can see that the `web` middleware group is also responsible for other things like providing the `$errors` variable on all views.

You can read more about it in the docs:

> By default, the `routes.php` file contains a single route as well as a route group that applies the `web` middleware group to all routes it contains. This middleware group provides session state and CSRF protection to routes.
>
> Any routes not placed within the `web` middleware group will not have access to sessions and CSRF protection, so make sure any routes that need these features are placed within the group. Typically, you will place most of your routes within this group:

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Thomas, I luckily got the same answer from a guy on github shortly before you posted :), you are both life savers.

Comment: Oh okay. :) I'm glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Though my route is in a group within the group that has a middleware `web`. So shouldn't my route be under the web middleware?

Comment: @majidarif Unfortunately, I would need to see some code to understand what's not working. It's probably best to open a new thread with the necessary code. :)