# Laravel session data is lost after click

Tags: php, laravel, session-variables, laravel-5

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        /*
         * TODO: Handle via CAS
         * Hardcoded for demo purposes
         */
        Session::put('isLogged', true);
        Session::put('index', "123456");

        return View::make('login');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        if(Session::get('isLogged') == true )
            return View::make('user');
    }
}
```

I have the following code. There is a link on login that goes to the FileControllers@user . On the second page my session data is lost (Session::all() is empty). What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Try switching your session driver (to possibly `array` or `database`) and then clear the config cache (`php artisan config:clear`). What's the result?

Comment: The data exists on FileController@login

Comment: Do you have the `web` middleware on your routes?

Comment: I just began to use Laravel, what's that?

Comment: Inside your `app/Http/routes.php` file, wrap your routes in a 
`Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    //
});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Laravel 5.2.10 Sessions wont persist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958607/my-laravel-5-2-10-sessions-wont-persist)

Comment: Nothing changed. The issue persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try wrapping your routes (inside `app/Http/routes.php`) in a `Route::group()` with the `web` middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // My Routes
});
```

An easy way to test this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('', function () {
        Session::set('test', 'testing');
    });

    Route::get('other', function () {
        dd(Session::get('test'));
    });
});
```

If you remove the web middleware, you'll receive `null` since the `web` middleware is responsible for starting the session.

Ensure you have the `web` middleware group inside your `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: Issue still persists.

Comment: Inside your `app/Http/Kernel.php`, do you have the middleware group `web`?

Comment: Strange... Change your session driver to `file` and then see if your session is created in `storage/framework/sessions`. You may need to clear the config cache for this to take effect.

Comment: Strange. Before I changed to another driver I was using file and the sessions were there. Now they aren't. However when I access / it dumps the correct data. Wtf? (I did clear cache)

Comment: Yea that's definitely odd. So it works though? If not, try clearing all caches (`route:clear, cache:clear, config:clear`)

Comment: It doesn't work, the session data is displayed at / but lost at /user ( I did clear all caches)