# Laravel session data empty after user login

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am using laravel version 6.17.0.

If I put data to session `Session::put('cart_merge', $data)` in `authenticated()` method of `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and I try to get them with `Session::get('cart_merge')` in Controller, the session **is empty**. If I do `Session::get('cart_merge')` right after insertion in `authenticated()` method, they are still there.

I tried grouping routes as adviced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140419/5821265 but it didn't help.

Why do session doesn't make it untill Controller?

AuthenticatesUsers.php:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $cart = getCart::getCart();
    $savedCart = $user->cart;

    if (empty($cart['cart'])){  // Shopping cart is empty
        $cart = [];
        foreach ($savedCart as $item) {
            $product = Product::where('id', $item->id)->where('visibility', 1)->where('stock', '>', 0)->first();
            if (is_null($product)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($item->pivot->amount > $product->stock){
                $cart[$item->id]['amount'] = $product->stock;
            }
            else {
                $cart[$item->id]['amount'] = $item->pivot->amount;
            }
            $cart[$item->id]['name'] = $product->name;
            $cart[$item->id]['url'] = $product->url;
            $cart[$item->id]['image'] = $product->image;
        }
        Session::put('cart', $cart);
    }
    else {  // There are some items in shopping cart.
        if ($savedCart->isEmpty()){     // User doesn't have any items saved in DB from last session.
            foreach ($cart['cart'] as $item_id => $item){
                DB::table('product_user')->insert([
                    'user_id' => $user->id,
                    'product_id' => $item_id,
                    'amount' => $cart['cart'][$item_id]['amount'],
                    'type' => 0
                ]);
            }
        }
        else {  // User has saved items in DB from last session.
            Session::put('cart_merge', $savedCart->toArray());
            // if I do Session::get('cart_merge') here, the data are correct.
        }
    }
}
```

SystemController.php:

```
class SystemController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $data = Session:get('cart_merge');
        dd($data);
        // if I do Session::get('cart_merge') here, null is returned instead of data.
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SystemController@index');
    Auth::routes();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing session driver to `SESSION_DRIVER=file` instead of `cookies` in `.env` file. It seems like cookies option isn't persistent.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing session in just in class directly

Session is depend on Request.

So might be your request method will route to some controller method and then u can access the session. otherwise how laravel will know whose session it is

Ex

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::get('', function () {
        Session::set('test', 'testing');
    });

    Route::get('other', function () {
        dd(Session::get('test'));
    });
});
```

check this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35140419/4153682

Comment: Of course I am calling the controller's method in route defined in web.php. Proposed solution (and link) is what I've already tried and wrote about in main post and it didn't help. The problem is when i try to put new data to session in authenticated() method, which is right after user logs in -- the data doesn't make it to the controller.