# Laravel 5 and OneLogin

Tags: php, laravel, session, onelogin

I use Laravel 5.2 and package [laravel-saml2](https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) to create simple SSO application.

I have a simple page with link http://laravel_url/private.
When user click on link I check in the session user status and if user not authenticated the application redirect to IDP.
According to the documentation, after successful authentication the IDP send a POST with user data to http://laravel_url/saml/acs url. On this step I try to save user data from IDP to session. However Laravel create a new file with session and I save user data into a new file.

How I can store user data in the same session file?

Comment: Oh, I found the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958607/my-laravel-5-2-10-sessions-wont-persist?rq=1 thanks :)

Comment: Nice you found the solution yourself, if you have any doubt related to laravel-saml2 or php-saml review the extense documentation is offered ;)