# Laravel 5 Session not available for the second page

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am New in Laravel, and using Laravel 5 
I am storing some values in Session like this

This is in a Controller with function say ABC

```
    Session::put('check_in', $check_in);
    Session::put('check_out', $check_out);
    Session::put('no_of_rooms', $no_of_rooms);
    Session::put('adult', $adult);
    Session::put('child', $child);
    return view('room');
```

I am getting the values of all these Sessions in rooms view, but now the problem is when I am going to some other link or on other page from this room view and using the Session as

```
    echo Session::get('check_in')."<br>";
    echo Session::get('check_out')."<br>";
    echo Session::get('no_of_rooms')."<br><br>";
    echo Session::get('adult')."<br>";
    echo Session::get('child')."<br>";
```

I am not able to get any of these Sessions value.

I am using Sessions so it has to be on all the pages till the Session flashed or browser gets closed, but its not retrieving any of the Session values..

I have seen may topics like this on Stack Overflow, but I am not able to understand those answers, Please Explain me thoroughly and solve this Problem, I am stucked at this part from last 4 to 5 days clueless.......

Comment: What is your session driver? It should be in `config/session.php`. If you are using the `file` driver, make sure your `framework/sessions` folder has write access to your web server. Also make sure you're not `exit()`ing anywhere, the Session data actually gets written to the session at the end of the request, so doing an `exit()` will actually stop it from getting written.

Comment: My Session Driver is file, And I don't know how to check whether my sessions directory has write access or not, I had deleted to check whether Session files are being made or not but they are not generating, and I am not using exit().

Comment: Hello Manish, you should consider reading the documentation before starting a project in a specific framework. You should know first of all the language (php) , the mvc pattern and then start with a framework. If you don't spend time reading the documentation you will have a lot of issues with you web application. Enjoy coding and keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

If your using Laravel 5.*, then you should use 'web' middleware in all routes to use session.

This looks like this: in routes.php in app/http directory

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

   Route::Auth();

   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
   Route::get('/login', 'UserController@userLoginView');
   Route::post('/login', 'UserController@userLogin');
}
```

You can use session in all those routes by declaring it under 'web' middleware.

I suggest you read more about 'web' middleware in Laravel 5.

Check this out: 
[My Laravel 5.2.10 Sessions wont persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958607/my-laravel-5-2-10-sessions-wont-persist?rq=1)

NOTE: As of Laravel 5.2.27 the web middleware is now in place by default,  Try removing the Route::group and see if that helps. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.2.27/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L56

Comment: I had tried to put it in middleware but its throwing Error of Token Mismatch Exception

Comment: you have to set a token in your form whenever you use Auth().

Comment: for starter you can remove   Route::Auth() in your code.

Comment: I have already put the token in my form, still its giving me Error

Answer (score 0):

Create a construction `__construct()` in your controllers that required the user to be connected:

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

and this automatically will check if the user is authenticated if not it will redirect them to login page